# Ternary with printf and exit function

Tags: c, printf, exit, ternary

I want to use a ternary this way

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

   *condition* ? (printf("some text") & exit(1)) : NULL;

   *some code*

   return 0;
};
```

, but when i compile the file i get this error

```
36:40: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
   36 |     condition ? (printf("Some text") & exit(1)) : NULL;
      |                                        ^~~~~~~
```

i have read some other topics, but i can't find anything enlightening to my situation. i want to if true the condition, to print a message informing that is necessary some arguments to the program to run and then exit because the program don't have the conditions necessary to run.

Comment: What do you expect `& exit(1)` to do? You haven't actually told us what the expected behaviour is for that whole expression. But the error is clear - `exit` returns nothing so you can't `&` it with anything else.

Comment: There must be a dedicated hell for programmers who abuse the ternary operator in places where a simple `if` would be appropriate.

Comment: If you want to unconditionally execute both `printf` and `exit`, use the comma operator instead of `&`.  However, unless this is meant to be part of some macro expansion, just use an `if` statement.

Comment: Try to avoid forcing the round-peg of a `if (...)` statement into the square-hole form of a *ternary*. You don't buy any performance and just end up with a less readable kludge.

Comment: @kaylum i want to if true the condition, to print a message informing that is necessary some arguments to the program to run and then exit because the program dont have the  conditions necessary to run.

Comment: @jamesdlin i didn't know i could use comma this way and this have solved my problem.

Comment: Still, an `if` would solve your problem much better. If you ever get in a situation where your code has to be reviewed by colleagues, don't expect much praise for such a line of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&` is a bitwise AND operation - it takes bits of two operands and computes bitwise AND of them. `exit()` function returns a `void` - you can't do calculations on a `void` value, it's a void.

Typically, [*comma operator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Comma_operator) `,` is used to chain commands in some context where only a single expression is allowed. The type of result of `,` operator is the type of the second expression.

There are specific rules for allowed types of expressions in [*conditional operator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator) `?:`, and types there can't be `void`.

The code could be made valid by, for example (assuming `condition` is valid):

```
condition ? printf("Some text"), exit(1), 0 : 0;
```

But really just:

```
if (condition) { printf("Some text"); exit(1); }
```

Comment: The good old `if (...)` beats trying to shoehorn a comma operator into the "if true" expression of a ternary any time. "But really just:" is a good way to put it.